# CKEditor shows me a textarea inside text input

Tags: php, twig, ckeditor

I have a problem with the render of my view.
Here is how I build my form :

```
$builder->add('intitule', CKEditorType::class, [
    'label'=>'NEW_CGU',
    'required'=>false,
    'data'=>'testj'
]);
```

I'm displaying it like this :

```
<div class="row m-0">
    <div class="col-xs-5 plr-16 pt-16 pb-16 background-white" style="width : 100%">
        {{ form_label(form.intitule) }}
        <textarea id="editor1" >
            {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'novalidate': 'novalidate' }}) }}

                {{ form_widget(form.intitule, { 'attr': { 'class': 'inscription plr-16' , 'rows' : '20'}}) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.intitule) }}
                 {#<p class="help-block">Maximum 500 caractères.</p>#}
        </textarea>
        <div class="text-right">
            <a href="{{ path('users_list') }}" class="button-square-prev">{{ "BACK"|trans }}</a>
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') %}
                <button disabled class="button-square" title="non accessible en consultation">Valider</button>
            {% else %}
            <button type="submit" class="button-square" onclick="return confirm('Êtes vous sûr de vouloir effectuer ces modifications?')">Valider</button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works, but there is something wrong with my display. I have a textarea within the "block text" of CKEditor

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Finally, my JS looks like this :

```
$(function() {

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                removePlugins: 'magicline',
                height: 400
            } );
    });
```

What am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: Hi, why do you add `'attr' => ['ckeditor']` to your form type ? What's its goal ?
By the way, you render your widget into a textarea tag O_o...

Comment: I saw it on another topic, but yes it can be removed (I've done it)
I'm just trying to display 'testj' (a real field in my db) into the text area of CKEditor, where I can modify it and save it so that's why I tried to render the form into it

Comment: Humm, as I said, you should avoid to render your widgets into html form inputs like you're doing...
Try to simply remove `<textarea id="editor1" >`

Comment: Your solution worked... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You may accept the answer for better visibility ;-) Glad I could solve your problem btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply render your widget out of html form inputs !
Remove your `<textarea id="editor1" >` tag.